# Query to check overlapping ranges in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have my table as

```
   From_Range      ToRange
   1                999
   9000             10000
   2000             5000
```

When I try to insert the range values 1000 - 3000 it should fail since some values within this new range fall between the existing range 2000 - 5000. How do I check whether the input range falls within the existing range?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way to find an overlap is like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE @myValueLo <= ExistingRangeEnd AND @myValueHi >= ExistingRangeStart)
  -- Overlaps
ELSE
  -- Doesn't overlap
```

This can be shown to work if you compare the condition above against each of the bars in the diagram below:

```
Existing range:         |-------------------|
Overlaps:       |-------------|       |------------|
                |----------------------------------|
                           |-------------|
Not overlaps:   |-----|                       |----|
```

in all the overlap cases, both these tests are true:

- the *start date* of the existing range is always before the *end date* of the new range
- the *end date* of the existing range is after the *start date* of the new range

Those that don't overlap fail one or other of this test.

Comment: myValueLow  <= ToRange AND myValueHigh  >= FromRange           OR      myValueHigh  <= ToRange AND myValueLow  >= FromRange  ? which is correct ?

Comment: Your first mirrors my answer, and the diagram demonstrates how a condition can be tested. Testing each of your suggestions is left as an exercise, unless you've found something significantly wrong with me answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
DECLARE @From Decimal = 2000
DECLARE @TO Decimal =5000

SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE  
(
 (
 @From BETWEEN OPEN_HRS AND (CLOSE_HRS - 1) 
 OR 
 @TO BETWEEN (OPEN_HRS + 1) AND CLOSE_HRS 
 ) 
OR
 (
 OPEN_HRS BETWEEN @From AND (@TO - 1)
 OR 
 CLOSE_HRS BETWEEN (@From + 1) AND @TO
 )
)
```