# SQL Query to check Range

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to write a SQL query that basically takes the starting and ending values that have already been inserted for a particular day and compares them with all of the starting and ending values to output everything that doesn't conflict. In other words, I am writing a scheduling application, that should tell a person the courses that they cannot take due to a scheduling conflict. This is what I have right now:

```
    SELECT C2.COURSENUM, C2.SECTIONID
    FROM TIMES T2, CLASSES C2
    WHERE T2.SECTIONID = C2.SECTIONID AND 
    (T2.MONSTART >= 
        (SELECT T.MONEND
        FROM DEGAUDIT D, UNDERGRAD S, TIMES T, CLASSES C
        WHERE D.SID = S.SID AND S.SSN = ? AND C.SECTIONID = T.SECTIONID 
        AND D.SECTIONID = C.SECTIONID)

        OR T2.MONEND <= 

            (SELECT T.MONSTART
            FROM DEGAUDIT D, UNDERGRAD S, TIMES T, CLASSES C
            WHERE D.SID = S.SID AND S.SSN = ? AND 
            C.SECTIONID = T.SECTIONID 
            AND D.SECTIONID = C.SECTIONID))
```

Where MonStart and MonEnd are my starting and ending times respectively. Right now, I am having troubles because both subqueries return more than one value which you cannnot use with the <= symbol or the >= symbol. Is there a way to accomplish this task using IN or NOT IN? Thank you! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL and/or sqlite? Try to re-write as join without sub-queries.

Comment: The objective of your question is not clear itself. Also, could you paste your tables' schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your question, just showing a single table 'times' to illustrate the idea.

What I'm suggesting is that you turn the logic round and compare the current time slot with all other time slots to see if there *are* any overlaps. If there are, then exclude the current time slot. So it would look like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE times
(
TimeID int,
StartTime Time,
EndTime Time
)

INSERT INTO times
VALUES
(1,'10:00:00','12:00:00'),
(2,'10:00:00','12:00:00'),
(3,'14:00:00','16:00:00'),
(4,'14:00:00','16:00:00'),
(5,'12:00:00','13:00:00'),
(6,'13:00:00','14:00:00')

SELECT  *
FROM times tim

WHERE not exists

(
    SELECT
    TimeID FROM
    times tom
    WHERE
    tom.EndTime>tim.StartTime
    AND
    tom.StartTime<tim.EndTime
    AND
    tom.TimeID<>tim.TimeID
)
```

Only the last two time slots have no overlap with any other time slots.

cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012099/query-to-check-overlapping-ranges-in-sql-server?rq=1), but you want < and > rather than <= and >= because you don't mind  if the ranges touch as long as the students can get from one class to the other quickly enough :-)