# Return overlap datetime record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the records where `Number` are equal and `StartTime` of the next row is `less than` the `EndTime` of the first row, but `UID` is different.

Here's the table I'm working with.

[image]

This is the output I'm trying to get:

[image]

Here's what I have come up with so far. (This query returns extra rows)

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUMBER ORDER BY STARTTIME)
   AS rownum
  FROM CALLS
)

SELECT r1.* FROM CTE r1 inner join CTE r2
 on r1.rownum = r2.rownum
 and r1.number = r2.number
 and r2.starttime < r1.endtime
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3630a/4)

Any suggestions how I can fix this query?

Comment: Do you want overlaps, or just based on start times?  For instance, there can be multiple records that don't overlap each other, but _do_ overlap some (much longer) span.  [There are answers for detecting overlaps already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012099/query-to-check-overlapping-ranges-in-sql-server/11012318#11012318).  Side note: your end time should be exclusive ("before this time" instead of "last instant of"), if they aren't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   calls 
WHERE  number IN (SELECT r1.number 
                  FROM   calls r1 
                         CROSS JOIN calls r2 
                  WHERE  r2.starttime < r1.endtime 
                         AND r1.number = r2.number 
                  GROUP  BY r1.number 
                  HAVING Count(1) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG`/`LEAD` to get previous/next record data:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3630a/42/0)**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    ID
    ,UID
    ,NUMBER
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
    ,LAG(EndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY StartTime) AS PrevEndTime
    ,LAG(UID) OVER(PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY StartTime) AS PrevUID
    ,(SELECT COUNT(Number) FROM CALLS c1 WHERE  c1.Number = c.Number)  AS Counter
  FROM CALLS c
)
SELECT
     ID
    ,UID
    ,NUMBER
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
FROM CTE
WHERE (StartTime < PrevEndTime OR PrevEndTime IS NULL)
  AND (PrevUID <> UID OR PrevUID IS NULL)
  AND Counter > 1
ORDER BY ID;
```